# Trouble replacing my handbrake

Tags: repair, handbrake

I have replaced the handbrake cable on my Vauxhall Corsa and adjusted it from the inside of the car but the back brakes are still not working properly. Any ideas on how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Did you adjust the rears or check to see if they were working?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What @Ben said :o)

Comment: It would help if you gave a bit more details @John, did you replace the cable because it failed or because your handbrake wasn't working? What's the history here?